# Is there a way to see which app sent data to Android VPN Service

Tags: android, android-vpn-service

I am currently using Hexene's LocalVPN implementation of Android's VPNService to monitor network traffic from my Android device. However, I was wondering if it was possible to see which app sent a particular packet.

I have tried searching online, and I have read through the documentation for LocalVPN to no avail :(

EDIT:

Sorry for not making it clear to begin with, I am trying to extend the application for my own development. Not just using the app as an application

Thank you for any help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question

Comment: You could revoke the internet permission of all your applications, except for one.

Comment: Sorry, I did not make that clear. I am currently writing my own application, by extending the LocalVPN. I was hoping to be able to somehow pull out the ID of another application, by adding to that project

Comment: Duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930342/how-to-get-uid-from-packet-android, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58497492/acccess-to-proc-net-tcp-in-android-q

Answer (score 0):

As of API level 29 (Android 10+), you can use [ConnectivityManager.getConnectionOwnerUid()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getConnectionOwnerUid(int,%20java.net.InetSocketAddress,%20java.net.InetSocketAddress)). Once you have the user ID you can call [PackageManager.getPackagesForUid()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getPackagesForUid(int)) to get the corresponding app ID(s).

For older Android versions, you can [parse /proc/net/*](https://github.com/M66B/NetGuard/blob/2.304/app/src/main/jni/netguard/ip.c#L384) to get the user ID. (Note that this method is [blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58497492/acccess-to-proc-net-tcp-in-android-q) on Android 10.)