# Permission Denied for access /proc/net/arp ARP table in Android 10

Tags: android

Using ARP table we can access IP and MAC of hotspot connected devices in Android 9 and earlier versions. Now from Android 10 permission denied for the same. Kindly suggest how can I access IP and MAC address of connected devices in Android 10. Below Code working in up-to Android 9 Version but not work in Android 10.

```
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
   String line;
   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] clientInfo = line.split(" +");
        if(!clientInfo[3].equalsIgnoreCase("type")) {
               String mac = clientInfo[3];
               String ip = clientInfo[0];
               textView.append("\n\nip: " + ip + " Mac: " + mac);
               Log.d("IP : ", ip);
               Log.d("Mac : ", mac);
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 8):

Run the `ip neigh show` command and process its output:

```
  val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
  val proc = runtime.exec("ip neigh show")
  proc.waitFor()
  val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(proc.inputStream))
```

You split the lines the same way, IP is [0], MAC is [4].

Comment: "ip neigh show" doesn't seem to work anylonger on Android 11 devices (and app targets SDK 30 or higher).

Comment: Bother, cat and mouse. I'm still on 10 with my phone but I use it actively in an app of mine...

Comment: Any solution for target 30? @Dieter27D

Answer (score 5):

Android 10 introduces several privacy-related restrictions that disallow apps to access certain information that could be potentially misused for fingerprinting and data collection. One of among them is the restriction on access to `/proc/net` filesystem on devices that run Android 10 or higher, apps cannot access `/proc/net`, which includes information about a device's network state. Apps that need access to this information, such as VPNs, should use the [`NetworkStatsManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager) or [`ConnectivityManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager) class.

The current APIs in Android doesn't allow apps to access the ARP cache. I see a bug is raised in Google issue tracker that is currently in the below status - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130103885

> Status: **Won't Fix (Infeasible)** We've passed along your input to our
> internal teams, who are evaluating it for a future release. We're
> closing this issue for now, and thanks for sending us your feedback!"

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#proc-net-filesystem

Related thread [ Acccess to `/proc/net/tcp` in Android Q ] - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58501039/4694013

Comment: Why Termux app still can execute these calls?